# counting pulses from a Mechanical water meter with Two inputs

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32

I want to count the number of pulses from a mechanical water meter using an STM32L Microcontroller. The outputs of the water meter are from TWO REED switches.

The operation of the Switches is explained as follows:

- the two Reed switches would be operated "ON" OR "OFF" respectively by the magnet fitted to the pointer or gear during its running on the register, but never "ON" at the same time.
- The two Reed switches operate two "ON" and two "OFF" in one round of the pointer/the gear means one signal output.

How can I read in the two inputs and be able to count the number of pulses in C? Note: 1 pulse = 100 liters.

Comment: When one switch closes, set a flag. When the other switch closes, clear the flag. Count the number of times the flag is cleared. I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: Could you draw a timing diagram of the state of two switches ? Your explanation is hard to understand.

Comment: It is not clear. Are you interested in how to configure the hardware to read the switches or you can read the switches already and interested in an algorithm to process the data?

Comment: STM32L what? L0, L1 or L4 it matters. Also add a link to the datasheet of the watermeter.

Comment: @Bence Kaulics- here is the link to the data sheet of the water meter https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sgrw61IOvCYlNZdDdXMnZZWDg/view           I can read either of the switches separately. Am only having issue combining the two outputs to make a round/cycle. Am using STM32L100RBT6

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're actually asking because what you seem to be asking is so simple whether you poll or use edge triggered interrupts.  The main issue is debouncing the switch signals.  For debouncing you should determine the maximum flow rate of your meter, which you don't really care about directly, but it will let you calculate the maximum switch period.  Use some significant portion of the minimum on or off time to perform your debounce.

Comment: Surely the point is you don't need to debounce with this system. It is like a mechanical clock escapement. You cannot count another A pulse until you have had a B pulse. A and B will never both be made at the same time. So from the point of view of an algorithm, debounce is irrelevant. When you get an A pulse, you wait for a B pulse. When you get a B pulse, you log another 100L and wait for an A pulse.

Comment: @WeatherVane:If a unit of flow occurs that turns the magnet near the reed the reed may flip, but then the magnet could go backwards a tiny amount (there is no 100% perfect ratchet).  This would be a pulse that shouldn't be counted because it's too short to be a real transition.  Also, if using interrupts to detect transitions then debouncing would consist of determining if a legal state of the switch had actually been reached.

Comment: it should not matter how many pulses you get off one reed switch, if the other switch is 180 degrees away and has no chance of a false make. I would have thought that is the whole *point* of having two switches, rather than one - to remove the need to debounce.

Answer (score 0):

The point of having two switches 180 degree apart, such that only one switch can be made at a time, is that no switch debouncing is needed.

In practice the code would need to be more sophisticated, but the basic algorithm can be represented by this:

```
while(1) {
    while(switchA() == 0);          // wait for switch A to be made
    litres += 100;                  // clock up unit volume
    display(litres);                // tell the user
    while(switchB() == 0);          // wait for switch B to be made
}
```

It does not matter how many pulses come from a reed switch, when it is near the magnet - all but the first pulse will be ignored, because the algorithm is then looking at the other switch.